# Determine the distance of a Vector 3 along another Vector 3

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, geometry

I have 2 3D vectors. (objects with X, Y and Z float values)

In my diagram below, I would like to determine the length of the green line.
This is the distance along Vector 1 that Vector 2 is. Or, the distance from the origin to the end of a line on Vector 1 which is at 90' to Vector 1 and passes thorough the point at the end of Vector 2.

[image]

I am doing this in Unity3D so I have access to quite a few helper methods that enable me to get the length of a Vector3 and so on very easily.

Comment: Simply LOOK AT THE DOCUMENTATION for Vector3.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html  You will quickly see that it includes functions such as `Project` (and similar functions), one of which is precisely what you want.

Comment: Purely FTR note that it's absolutely impossible to know where your diagram is pointing in 3D space  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is so useful, I thought I was familiar with Vector3 but I guess I have always missed that (theres no need to be rude though :/ )  Also your second comment is quite correct but also it doesnt matter, the answer I seek should work for any arrangement, the only important thing is that the black line is perpendicular to the red one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length is obviously

```
norm(v2)*cos(angle(v1,v2))
```

and since

```
cos(angle(v1,v2))=abs(dot(v1,v2))/norm(v1)/norm(v2)
```

the final formula is

```
abs(dot(v1,v2))/norm(v1)
```

---

One could also say that

```
e1 = v1/norm(v1)
```

is the unit vector in the direction of `v1`, and that the green vector is

```
dot(e1,v2)*e1
```

resulting in the same length formula.

Comment: Hi LutzL. This is mathematically admirable, but note that since this is in a game engine (Unity3D), the solution is instantly available.  the question is about the `Vector3` datatype in Unity. The OP need only check the doco for `Vector3` and instantly find a solution.

Comment: Ok, that would be `(Vector3.Project(v2,v1)).magnitude`. However, `abs(Vector3.Dot(v1,v2))/v1.magnitude` has less operations involved, since there is no construction of an intermediate temporary `Vector3` instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is projection of Vector2 onto Vector1 direction. The simplest way (I think) to find it  - using scalar product

D = |**V2**| * DotProduct(**V2**, **V1**) / (|**V2**| * |**V1**|) = DotProduct(**V2**, **V1**) / |**V1**|

where |**V1**| is the length of **V1** vector

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think this is what you wanted

```
Vector3 distance = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, vector_1, vector_2.sqrMagnitude / vector_1.sqrMagnitude);
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html